# How do I get metadata from sqlalchemy to display in jinja as a table?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a few databases in postgres and mysql. I would like the user to connect to the database by providing credentials, and then display the metadata of the tables (as tables) on the html that he is viewing.

This is the relevant code.

```
meta = MetaData()
meta.reflect(bind=eng)

return str(meta.tables)
```

This returns the following of the type `<class 'sqlalchemy.util._collections.immutabledict'>`

```
immutabledict({'categories': Table('categories', MetaData(bind=None), Column('category', INTEGER(), table=, primary_key=True, nullable=False, server_default=DefaultClause(, for_update=False)), Column('categoryname', VARCHAR(length=50), table=, nullable=False), schema=None), 'inventory': Table('inventory', MetaData(bind=None), Column('prod_id', INTEGER(), table=, primary_key=True, nullable=False), Column('quan_in_stock', INTEGER(), table=, nullable=False), Column('sales', INTEGER(), table=, nullable=False), schema=None), 'products': Table('products', MetaData(bind=None), Column('prod_id', INTEGER(), table=, primary_key=True, nullable=False, server_default=DefaultClause(, for_update=False)), Column('category', INTEGER(), table=, nullable=False), Column('title', VARCHAR(length=50), table=, nullable=False), Column('actor', VARCHAR(length=50), table=, nullable=False), Column('price', NUMERIC(precision=12, scale=2), table=, nullable=False), Column('special', SMALLINT(), table=), Column('common_prod_id', INTEGER(), table=, nullable=False), schema=None), 'reorder': Table('reorder', MetaData(bind=None), Column('prod_id', INTEGER(), table=, nullable=False), Column('date_low', DATE(), table=, nullable=False), Column('quan_low', INTEGER(), table=, nullable=False), Column('date_reordered', DATE(), table=), Column('quan_reordered', INTEGER(), table=), Column('date_expected', DATE(), table=), schema=None), 'cust_hist': Table('cust_hist', MetaData(bind=None), Column('customerid', INTEGER(), ForeignKey('customers.customerid'), table=, nullable=False), Column('orderid', INTEGER(), table=, nullable=False), Column('prod_id', INTEGER(), table=, nullable=False), schema=None), 'customers': Table('customers', MetaData(bind=None), Column('customerid', INTEGER(), table=, primary_key=True, nullable=False, server_default=DefaultClause(, for_update=False)), Column('firstname', VARCHAR(length=50), table=, nullable=False), Column('lastname', VARCHAR(length=50), table=, nullable=False), Column('address1', VARCHAR(length=50), table=, nullable=False), Column('address2', VARCHAR(length=50), table=), Column('city', VARCHAR(length=50), table=, nullable=False), Column('state', VARCHAR(length=50), table=), Column('zip', INTEGER(), table=), Column('country', VARCHAR(length=50), table=, nullable=False), Column('region', SMALLINT(), table=, nullable=False), Column('email', VARCHAR(length=50), table=), Column('phone', VARCHAR(length=50), table=), Column('creditcardtype', INTEGER(), table=, nullable=False), Column('creditcard', VARCHAR(length=50), table=, nullable=False), Column('creditcardexpiration', VARCHAR(length=50), table=, nullable=False), Column('username', VARCHAR(length=50), table=, nullable=False), Column('password', VARCHAR(length=50), table=, nullable=False), Column('age', SMALLINT(), table=), Column('income', INTEGER(), table=), Column('gender', VARCHAR(length=1), table=), schema=None), 'orders': Table('orders', MetaData(bind=None), Column('orderid', INTEGER(), table=, primary_key=True, nullable=False, server_default=DefaultClause(, for_update=False)), Column('orderdate', DATE(), table=, nullable=False), Column('customerid', INTEGER(), ForeignKey('customers.customerid'), table=), Column('netamount', NUMERIC(precision=12, scale=2), table=, nullable=False), Column('tax', NUMERIC(precision=12, scale=2), table=, nullable=False), Column('totalamount', NUMERIC(precision=12, scale=2), table=, nullable=False), schema=None), 'orderlines': Table('orderlines', MetaData(bind=None), Column('orderlineid', INTEGER(), table=, nullable=False), Column('orderid', INTEGER(), ForeignKey('orders.orderid'), table=, nullable=False), Column('prod_id', INTEGER(), table=, nullable=False), Column('quantity', SMALLINT(), table=, nullable=False), Column('orderdate', DATE(), table=, nullable=False), schema=None)})
```

I have tried a for loop on this in the jinja template but it says `sqlalchemy 'table' object is not iterable`

How do I get my metadata from database to display as tables in the html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`inspector`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/reflection.html#fine-grained-reflection-with-inspector) class helps access metadata.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine import reflection
engine = create_engine('...')
insp = reflection.Inspector.from_engine(engine)
print(insp.get_table_names())
```

Other methods which are available are

```
get_check_constraints
get_columns
get_foreign_keys
get_indexes
get_pk_constraint
get_schema_names
```

Refer the documentation for the description and more methods. You can then transfer the variables to the jinja template and print it accordingly.

This is what I did for my working example.

```
tablenames = insp.get_table_names()
return render_template('tables.html', inspector=insp, table=tablenames)
```

Jinja:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>table</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>type</th>
        <th>nullable</th>
        <th>default</th>
        <th>autoincrement</th>
        <th>comment</th>
    </tr>
    {% for table in table %}
        {% for col in inspector.get_columns(table_name=table) %}
            <tr>
            <td>{{ table }}</td>
            {% for val in col.values() %}
                <td>{{ val }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```